# vscode fails to HotReload on latest Flutter version

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter, hot-reload

After latest Flutter 1.0 stable and Dart update to vscode, I,m unable to use hotreload from vscode. If I run it from a terminal everytnhing works fine. Flutter doctor has no complains and I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried to uninstall flutter and dart from vscode but no luck so far. The error I get is

> ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/object.h: 8954: error: Handle check
>   failed: saw Instance of 'HomePage' expected Closure

I searched to find a solution but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Dart or Flutter. It's possible it's the same as this one:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24710

Can you reproduce in a small sample that you could easily  attach to that issue and add some notes on your environment (what platform, what device, etc.) and if you get a full stack trace dumped when this happens, include that too.

Thanks!

Comment: Just added flutter doctor and trace